# Creating a summary statistic table from MULTIPLE categories within a variable

Tags: r, dataframe, datatable, dplyr, summary

I have a data frame that looks something like this:

```
 ID    category                          Household Income     Tercile   
  1     unmarried couple                    100,000             Middle
  2     married couple                      150,000             Bottom
  3     single Female head of Household     90,000              Top
  4     single Male Head of Household       80,000              Bottom
```

I want to create a summary statistic table that shows the sd, mean, min, max, median of the household income for each observation grouped by each category AND tercile.

I was able to generate a similar table for one of the categories. This is the code for unmarried couples:

First, I separated out the category from the overall dataframe and removed the variables I didn't need:

```
status_unmarried <- merged_data %>% 
select(-(person_id:is_college_graduate)) %>%
select(-(is_urban:is_owner_of_home)) %>%
filter(category == 'unmarried couple') %>%
group_by(hh_income, tercile_of_census_tract_income) %>% 
distinct(hh_id, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

Then generated the necessary summary statistics:

```
library(dplyr)
table_one <- tableby(tercile_of_census_tract_income ~ ., data = 
status_unmarried)
summary(table_one, title = "Unmarried households")
```

I could reiterate this process for the remaining three categories. However, I would prefer to generate this table by aggregating all the categories into one block of code; and not having to create each table separately based on category. The table or data frame would look something like this

```
        Unmarried Couple   Married Couple  Single Female Head Single Male Head

Bottom
Mean
Median
Min
Max
SD
Sample Size

Middle
Mean
Median
Median
Min
Max
SD
Sample Size

Top
Mean
Median
Min
Max
SD
Sample Size
```

Sample size represents how many households belong to each category. So I want the columns to be categories and each row to be the statistic but further divided up by tercile. I want to create a data frame or summary table with these results.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You'll likely get a more responsive audience if you provide a representative subset of your data in your question. A handy function to get this is `dput`. That said, functions like `dplyr::summarize_at` will likely come in handy here.

Comment: Rather than editing "CLOSED" into your question title, you can indicate your problem is solved by accepting one of the answers - click the checkmark in the left margin next to the answer you want to accept.

Answer (score 0):

Consider nested base R's `by` which provides a console report with section breaks and headers:

```
tercile_agg_df_list <- by(random_df, random_df$Tercile, function(sub_df) {
   by_list <- by(sub_df, sub_df$category, function(core_df)          
     with(core_df,
          c(mean = mean(Household_Income),  median = median(Household_Income), 
            min = min(Household_Income), max = max(Household_Income),
            sd = sd(Household_Income), sample_size = length(Household_Income))
         )
     )       
   t(do.call(rbind, by_list))
})

tercile_agg_df_list
# random_df$Tercile: Bottom
#             Married Couple Single Female Head Single Male Head Unmarried Couple
# mean             44632.894        50204.52677        58095.923       52521.3178
# median           49678.238        50042.54136        62158.775       51933.3694
# min               1989.695           95.23595         6220.779         676.9893
# max              95896.827        98471.19979        98317.740       94795.6344
# sd               29246.103        31317.47006        25728.368       28013.6172
# sample_size         35.000           56.00000           44.000          39.0000
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
# random_df$Tercile: Middle
#             Married Couple Single Female Head Single Male Head Unmarried Couple
# mean             56302.818          54845.140        42645.032         48222.93
# median           63245.388          51364.262        39126.608         49713.41
# min               2690.053           5286.126         3687.153          3430.90
# max              99327.726          99216.564        98645.000         98400.38
# sd               28582.935          32262.149        29996.185         28485.63
# sample_size         42.000             44.000           38.000            44.00
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
# random_df$Tercile: Top
#             Married Couple Single Female Head Single Male Head Unmarried Couple
# mean             51437.876         45495.1326     55150.495621        44958.808
# median           54592.978         42051.5708     56452.659052        45982.775
# min               3917.729           376.2815         1.451327         1216.967
# max              99638.078         95885.3950     99429.982156        99412.446
# sd               27627.480         26643.9194     30690.131884        29713.131
# sample_size         46.000            39.0000        31.000000           42.000
```

Data

```
set.seed(4242019)
categs <- c("Unmarried Couple", "Married Couple", "Single Female Head", "Single Male Head")

random_df <- data.frame(
  category = sample(categs, 500, replace=TRUE),
  Tercile = sample(c("Bottom", "Middle", "Top"), 500, replace=TRUE),
  Household_Income = runif(500) * 10E4
)

head(random_df)
#           category Tercile Household_Income
# 1 Unmarried Couple  Bottom        70118.908
# 2   Married Couple     Top        24069.175
# 3 Unmarried Couple     Top         1216.967
# 4 Unmarried Couple  Bottom        47936.147
# 5   Married Couple     Top        80633.299
# 6   Married Couple     Top        46136.093
```

Comment: What is the sub_df function supposed to do?

Comment: It is the iterator variable (the df subsets from `by` call) passed into the anonymous function. You can name it anything! Same with the inner `core_df`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code from *data.table* package. You might have to convert the dataframe into data.table by using *as.data.table* function. Considering the dataframe name is dt,

```
dt[, .(Min=min(Income), First_quartile=quantile(Income, 0.1),
   Median=quantile(Income, 0.5), Mean=mean(Income),
   Third_Quartile=quantile(Income, 0.75),
   Max=max(Income)) ,
by=.(Category, Tercile)]
```

This will generate the table in another format, but I think it is more organized.